# How put ResouceBundle in the ContextMenu

Tags: java, javafx

I'm create my first app with JavaFX and works good at so far.

On the FXMLLoader i can load a ResourceBundle file, but i don't find any function that's do the same function in the ContextMenu

My working code

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("mymoney/view/linguas/messages");

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass()
                    .getResource(fxmlPath));
            loader.setResources(bundle);
```

My ContextMenu

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem cut = new MenuItem("%commos.menu.cut");
        MenuItem edit = new MenuItem("editar");
        MenuItem paste = new MenuItem("Paste");
        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(cut, edit, paste);
        cut.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Cut...");
            }
        });
```

Anyone can show me the path?

Comment: And what would this `.setResouce` method do, if it existed?

Comment: @fabian I edit the question and put the code do load the screen

Comment: But what's the connection to `ContextMenu`?

Comment: @Krismorte you need to make your question much clearer, by (at the very least) answering fabian's question. Apart from the fact that the code you have shown doesn't actually have a context menu, a context menu is an object that has a bunch of `MenuItem`s, and some mechanisms for showing it on the screen. What would you expect it to do if you called `setResource(bundle);`? There is no obvious meaning for this functionality.

Comment: @James_D I edit the question. See if it's more clear.

Comment: Not really. The `%commos.menu.cut` looks like you are trying to use the FXML syntax for resource resolution in Java code, which obviously doesn't work. You haven't provided any context at all for this code, but are you trying to do `MenuItem cut = new MenuItem(bundle.getString("commos.menu.cut"));`? Obviously that assumes that wherever you are setting up the `ContextMenu` has access to  `bundle`.

Comment: @James_D it works, thanks!
When I create the question I think that theres a better form to do that, like the FXMLLoader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a `MenuItem` using a String defined in a resource bundle, you would do

```
MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(bundle.getString(resourceKey));
```

where `bundle` is the `ResourceBundle` and `resourceKey` is the key that maps in the bundle to the desired value.